# Connecting to MySQL in AutoPlay Media Studio

Tags: mysql

I wanna to connect to a Mysql database on my host through AMS 8
The Database Remote is open and i added % in remote mysql to allow any IP to access db
can you just give me a simple code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first enable Databse support in your AMS project. After that you'll get MySQL Lua's representive commands binded in Action menu.
The chunk for connecting your db will look like this

```
MySQLConnection, err = MySQL:connect("database", "user", "pswd", "localhost", "port");
```